# pm2 starts two apps with same name and other versions

Tags: node.js, pm2

When I am executing this script it starts two apps with same name and other versions

```
pm2 start --name rpc --log RPC_LOG_FILE node dist/main.js
```

[image]

logs are same, but when I start with ecosystem config file it starts 1 app.

I don’t want to use config file, this is the first time I met this issue, is there a way to fix this or is this normal and what is the purpose ?

Comment: two apps with same name.

Comment: it this suggestion for edit?

Answer (score 1):

Start pm2 by `process_id`.

In your case it is `3` or `4`

```
pm2 start <process_id> --log RPC_LOG_FILE node dist/main.js
```

You can rename your process names

```
pm2 restart id|name -n newname
```

or

```
pm2 delete id|name  
pm2 start app.js -n newname
```

Comment: I have also added `-f` flag like this
`pm2 start 0 -f --name rpc --log RPC_LOG_FILE node dist/main.js`
I have deleted all processes so after starting new ones `ids` have changed

Comment: Thank you but, this is script for ci/cd so it can be server problem and delete or rename command will do wrong job on other servers

Answer (score 0):

:D problem is that I was running also node command  `node dist/main.js` which is wrong, must be `dist/main.js`